# on the Frobenius number (J. L Davison)

Tags: combinatorics

In studying J. L. Davison's "On the linear diophantine problem of Frobenius" (J. of Number Theory 48, 353-363 (1994)) I got stuck on the last paragraph of the proof of theorem 3.2. The cases $b/d<c/d<a$ and $b/d<a<c/d$ are ommited and I am unable to finish the proof in these cases. I tried to contact Prof. Davison in a number of ways (email, Laurentian U., coauthors) to no avail. If anyone can help me by either  providing a proof for the missing cases and/or giving me a sure way to contact Prof. Davison directly, I would be be happy e grateful.

Comment: Either you forgot to include that paragraph or else you're extremely optimistic if you think there will be many, or even a few, that will go to search for that paper and look for that reference...

Comment: Please see corrected text above. Thanks.

Comment: I hope to find someone who might have done some work on  Davison's article; maybe I'll get lucky!

Answer (score 0):

The Laurentian University [website](https://laurentian.ca/program/mathematics-ba/details) has no mention of J. L. Davison.

This is hardly surprising, as the paper in question is 24 years old.  The author's last paper appears to have been published over a decade ago.  It would appear that J. L. Davison is retired.

Further, even if you could track down this author, it is quite unlikely that you would be able to get useful information here.  I have published papers much less than 24 years ago, whose details I have no recollection of.

As DonAntonio points out in the comments, you are better off asking a new question, where you post more details of the incomplete proof (rather than a citation), and asking for help to fill in those details.